# How to store map in .properties file that is used by Spring project?

Tags: java, spring

Is it the good idea to store map like that:

```
myMap=k1:v1,k2:v2,k3:v3
```

and then parse its value as Map object?

[Update]
What is the best way to store map in properties file (as whole properties file or just part of it), and how to access that whole map (not just one key/value from the map)?

Comment: I would not recommend it. Make a separate properties file just for that map and put them as `k1=v1`, etc.

Comment: And if I have map of maps? What should I do?

Comment: Then use some other serialization technique, like json or XML.

Answer (score 1):

The Properties class implements Map Just define the properties bean like so:

```
<util:properties id="myMap" location="classpath:myMap.properties" />
```

then set a reference to myMap in your bean that needs the properties.

Comment: and what if i have already defined PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer that includes that property file?

Comment: Can you not make a property file just for your map called myMap.properties like in the example above? Each key value pair is a new line in the property file e.g k1=v1

Comment: I need separate map, because my program knows key names only in runtime. So i can't just write @Value("${k1}") String k1; because myMap is used like myMap.containsKey(keyNameFromRuntime).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the spring MapFactoryBean.  Spring will give you map when you ask for the bean.

```
<bean id="myBean" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MapFactoryBean">
    <property name="sourceMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="k1">
                <value>v1</value>
            </entry>
            <entry key="k2">
                <value>v2</value>
            </entry>
            <entry key="k3">
                <value>v3</value>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="targetMapClass" value="java.util.TreeMap"/>
</bean>
```